# Farewell message to passed away friend

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

How to write a farewell message to one my friend who passed away recently. Here is my try.

> There are no words to express my sadness. He is cannot be forgotten. I was lucky to meet a person like him in my life.

or

> It is really sad to see him leaving us. He was one of the best, honest and 
>   respectful person I never met in my life.

Is this ok? I am not a native speaker and I really would like to say something to his family and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sounds more like an obituary for a deceased friend, although i would probably say "I was lucky to **know**..." rather than "I was lucky to **meet**..."

Something in the tone of the second example sounds more like a farewell to a person who is moving away, retiring from a job, or the like, but is not dead or dying. Particularly "It is really sad to see him leaving us" where "leaving" seems to suggest an action in progress, not over with as a death is. Also it should be "..one of the best, **most** honest and respectful **people** I **ever** met...."  "One of" must agree with "people" not "person", "never" is just an error, and one can't have "one of the honest".

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. He is a friend who passed away recently.